# java -version doesn't display the value of JAVA_HOME

Tags: java

I've installed jdk 7 and set up the "JAVA_HOME" to this version. Then, I've installed jdk 6 and I've updated the "JAVA_HOME" to point to jdk 6. After closing and reopening the system, when typing "java -version", I got always :

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode, sharing)
```

However, when typing

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

I got :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
```

I didn't understand why `java -version` don't display the value of "JAVA_HOME"

Comment: Check the PATH env.variable. That must be pointing to the old one... When you type `java` in the shell, the OS will try to find the executable. It looks in the current working directory, and then looks on the PATH...

Comment: `which java` will tell you which binary gets called.

Comment: I changed the PATH too to point to :
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Comment: Resolved when putting the new value at the first of System PATH env variable . So when typing echo %PATH%, I get :
C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
When it was set in user PATH env var, it's displayed at the end when typing eco %PATH%, as if it was overrided :
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 7 puts a java.exe in c:\windows\system32. You could try to delete these exe's, but I'm not sure Windows will allow it, or restore it after a reboot.

If you want to override it, you must put %JAVA_HOME%\bin as first entry in your PATH, before c:\windows\system32.

Answer (score 0):

Which java starts when you run `java -version` depends on the PATH env variable, not JAVA_HOME. OS will be looking for java.exe (Windows) like for any other program

Comment: PATH is set to jdk 1.6. When typing echo %PATH%, I get :      C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Comment: Resolved when putting the new value at the first of System PATH env variable . So when typing echo %PATH%, I get : C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\S‌​ystem32\Wbem. When it was set in user PATH env var, it's displayed at the end when typing eco %PATH%, as if it was overrided : C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Answer (score 0):

if you run java on your command window, it takes java from the PATH variable. JAVA_HOME is used my maven etc...

Comment: thanks for info, but PATH is set to jdk 1.6. When typing echo %PATH%, I get : C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Comment: Make sure java is not available in C:\WINDOWS\system32

Comment: Resolved when putting the new value at the first of System PATH env variable . So when typing echo %PATH%, I get : C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\S‌​‌​ystem32\Wbem. When it was set in user PATH env var, it's displayed at the end when typing eco %PATH%, as if it was overrided : C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `PATH` variable is pointing to JAVA version `1.7.0_40/bin` directory.

Comment: PATH is set to jdk 1.6. When typing echo %PATH%, Iget : C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Comment: @have u re-launched the console after changing your PATH variable

Comment: Resolved when putting the new value at the first of System PATH env variable . So when typing echo %PATH%, I get : C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\S‌​‌​ystem32\Wbem. When it was set in user PATH env var, it's displayed at the end when typing eco %PATH%, as if it was overrided : C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, this is nothing to do with your JAVA_HOME environment variable. You are getting java version from `C:\windows\system32\java.exe`.

If you don’t want that behaviour then in system variables section put %JAVA_HOME%\bin as starting element (Of course you should have JAVA_HOME). (I thought of adding image but I dont have enough reputation to do so :( )